# Как получить последний ID в таблице движка ДЛЕ?

Tags: php

```
    <?php 
    $user = "123";
    $pass = "123";
    $database = "door";

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass, $database);


   //тут получить получить max ID из таблицы `dle_post`;

    mysqli_close($link);
```

php 7.0. Использую MYSQLI. Не могу взять и положить последний максимальный ID В переменную.
Везде пишется про:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

Но этот запрос у меня не работает. возвращает объект пустым, хотя данные есть.

Comment: Вопрос - __зачем__ это вам? Вообще есть запрос `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` но может быть он вам и не нужен.

Comment: SELECT id FROM `table_name` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1

Comment: Чтобы знать, сколько спарсилось строк и проводить дальнейшие операции.

Comment: SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1  -  как вернуть результат запроса?

Comment: А если некоторые ИД будут удалены? Например `1,2,3,4,7,8`?

Comment: мне нужен лишь последний, просто число последней строки.

Comment: [Вывести результат запроса](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82+mysql+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0&oq=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82+mysql+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.10423j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @АлексейРожков `mysqli_insert_id()` после запроса к БД пропишите.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dle_post`";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;

Вот рабочий вариант в вашем случае.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Как сделать его ответом к вопросу?

Comment: ненужно ничего делать ответом к этому вопросу.